# Using Sqlite in a server application? Alternatives?

Tags: database, sqlite, client-server

Consider the following scenario:
A database is to be used on a local network, to which a handful of clients connect at one time. There is one table. When one of the clients modifies the data in that table, the other connected clients should be notified. Perhaps there could be one thread in the server application per connection.

One constraint is that should not require the user to install and configure any other third-party database software. This is why Sqlite came to mind, since the application itself could just interact with the .db file, which can be bundled with it.

Is this something that is achievable with Sqlite, or is this idea totally wrong and misguided?

Simple diagram illustrating this description.
[image]

Comment: Who is "the user" in this case? I am confused because you mention "clients" (plural) and then "user" (singular). What I suggest is to draw a simple diagram to describe the various components that interact. From that, it will be easier to reason about.

Comment: @marco.m the "user" would be using the client application on their machine. Added a diagram illustrating this situation.

Comment: Thanks, it is now clearer. What it still confusing is the constraint that the client (I am using the term "client" because this is what the "user" means) should not install any database software: according to your diagram, there is a real server that abstracts away the DB, so also if the server were using a DB server and not SQLite, the client in both cases would not have to install anything (besides the client app)... Is the connection between client and server something like HTTP?

Comment: @marco.m the server application should be able to be distributed and work "out of the box", with the bundled .db file, so that there would be no need to install anything like Sql Server or MySql, etc on the server computer. For the connection, yes it is something like HTTP or TCP, I am not too fussed about which protocol is used.

Comment: Ah Now it is clear. So the answer is yes, you can use SQLite for this architecture. You may also want to enable WAL (https://sqlite.org/wal.html), in your case for increased concurrency. For the notification part of the question, you can investigate triggers (https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: @marco.m thank you, I will have a look at those links. Could you post this as answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the exchange of comments:

the answer is yes, you can use SQLite for this architecture.

You may also want to enable [WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) (Write-Ahead Logging), in your case for increased concurrency:

> ...
> There are advantages and disadvantages to using WAL instead of a rollback journal. Advantages include:
>
> 1. WAL is significantly faster in most scenarios.
> 2. WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.
> 3. Disk I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL.
> 4. WAL uses many fewer fsync() operations and is thus less vulnerable to problems on systems where the fsync() system call is broken.
>
> But there are also disadvantages:
> ...

For the notification part of the question, I suggest to investigate [triggers](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

> ...
> Triggers are database operations that are automatically performed when a specified database event occurs.
>
> Each trigger must specify that it will fire for one of the following operations: DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE.
> ...